# VS2015: Migrated project compiles, but won't run ("Debug Assertion Failed!")

Tags: .net, c++-cli, visual-studio-2015

I have a program that was original compiled in VS2013. Now that I have VS2015 installed, I have been having issues even getting my application to compile. It is written in C++/CLI. It originally targeted the v120_xp toolset. I tried compiling with that targeted toolset (along with all C++ libraries my program utilizes, which are GraphicsMagick and libsquish). It wouldn't even compile if it targeted that toolset. So I tried targeting v140_xp (a few of the users of my program still use Windows XP). That didn't work either.

So I decided to just target the v140 toolset, and .NET framework version 4.5.2 (it originally targeted 4.0).

It compiled successfully.

But now my program won't even start up. I debug it and I get this:

```
Exception thrown at 0x77751ed2 in PathCreator.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x23462c5f.
Debug Assertion Failed!

Program: ...Visual Studio 2015\Projects\PathCreator\Debug\PathCreator.exe
File: minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\heap\debug_heap.cpp
Line: 1037

Expression: _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(block)

For information on how your program can cause an assertion
failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.

(Press Retry to debug the application)
'PathCreator.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\syswow64\dwmapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
PathCreator.exe has triggered a breakpoint

Exception thrown at 0x53cb6866 in PathCreator.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x23462c70.
Exception thrown at 0x76d23e28 in PathCreator.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in Unknown Module.
Additional information: The type initializer for '<Module>' threw an exception.

An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in Unknown Module.
Additional information: The type initializer for '<Module>' threw an exception.

The program '[4156] PathCreator.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
The program '[4156] PathCreator.exe: Native' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
```

I have no idea why this is happening. I'm almost ready to just uninstall VS2015 and go back to VS2013.

Any ideas on what is going on? Any help or pointers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you clean and recompile the entire project? I recently switched to 2015 too and had no such issues after upgrading my projects.

Comment: The first exception might be getting caught and handled internally, which leads to the second.  The `Expression: _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(block)` indicates that memory has corrupted, possibly due to writing past the end of a buffer or writing past the end of a class because the writer assumes the class is larger than was allocated (like when it is expecting a derived class and gets a base class, or object of a different class).  Change the exception settings to stop when the 0xC0000005 error is initially thrown so you can see the initial problem.

Comment: @KompjoeFriek Yes, I cleaned the entire project and recompiled. I also recompiled GraphicsMagick and libsquish to target the v140 toolset and it compiled just fine.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Thanks, I'll try that. How do I change the exception settings to stop when 0xC0000005 is thrown? I'm not very good at debugging (although I should be, it's something I'm going to have to work on).

Comment: From the debug menu, windows submenu, "Exception settings".  Expand the "Win32 exceptions" section and check the box next to the 0xC0000005 exception.

Comment: Hmm, it was already checked. It seems whatever is going wrong happens before the main() function is even called in my application. If I try and debug in Release mode, VS says "Windows has triggered a breakpoint in PathCreator.exe. This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in PathCreator.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded." I haven't changed a single line of code since I upgraded to VS2015 and it was compiling just fine in VS2013.

Comment: When I select "Break" in that window, a "No Symbols Loaded" tab appears, saying  "wntdll.pdb not loaded. wntdll.pdb contains the debug information required to find the source for the module ntdll.dll". Any ideas? I'm so stumped.

Comment: A few ideas to try.  Make sure all of the libraries you link with were built with the 2015 compiler.  When you hit the breakpoint in debug_heap, look up the call stack to see where that call comes from.  That won't be the problem (just where it is first noticed) but some activity earlier in that function or it's caller might have caused the problem.  Try looking at the content of the memory flagged by debug_heap (in one of the memory debug windows) and see what got written there.

Comment: I'm having similar issues with an upgrade project - did you find a solution?

Comment: I did not. I'm not sure what's causing the issue - I'm just rewriting the program, I've been meaning to switch to WPF from WinForms anyway. I searched everywhere and couldn't find a solution. What is your project written in? I think it has something to do with C++/CLI, because all of my other projects work just fine.

Comment: My issue seems to be related to statics in C++ and the DLL initialization code. I suspect a VS2015 bug at this point.

Comment: You might want to take a look at my question (solved) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35575805/afxwin-h-issues-in-visual-studio-2015-windows-form-app

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get rid of this problem (so far) by changing the entry point to my program. In the project's Properties page, under Linker->Advanced, I cleared the "Entry Point" option (it was "main"). I then changed my main method (originally defined by an earlier version of Visual Studio as "int main(array ^args)") to "int WinMain(void *var1, unsigned long var2, void *var3)".

According to the VS Help, letting the compiler choose the entry point allows it to make sure "...the C run-time library is initialized correctly, and C++ constructors for static objects are executed". Sounds like the problem we've been having.

I'm not sure whether this problem is showing up now because Microsoft doesn't support winforms in managed C++ anymore or it it is to do with their rearchitecture of the CRT (or something completely different). I'm also not sure whether this is THE correct solution but it seems to have worked for the program I'm working on at the moment.