# C++/CLI DLL crashes on load after port to VS2015 / .NET 4.6

Tags: .net, dll, c++-cli, visual-studio-2015

Honestly, this is may be a dupe of [VS2015: Migrated project compiles, but won't run ("Debug Assertion Failed!")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32291678/vs2015-migrated-project-compiles-but-wont-run-debug-assertion-failed) but that has no answer and I have more details.

Recently ported our codebase from VS2010 targeting v4.0 to VS2015 targeting v4.6. We have a managed C++ DLL to provide .NET access to our C++ codebase. All .NET applications which reference it crash on startup. It seems to be crashing registering statics for destruction at exit.

Here is the debug callstack:

```
ntdll.dll!RtlValidateHeap() Unknown
KernelBase.dll!_HeapValidate@12()   Unknown
ucrtbased.dll!_CrtIsValidHeapPointer(const void * block) Line 1385  C++
ucrtbased.dll!_msize_dbg(void * block, int block_use) Line 1037 C++
ucrtbased.dll!_msize(void * block) Line 30  C++
ucrtbased.dll!_recalloc_dbg(void * block, unsigned int count, unsigned int element_size, int block_use, const char * file_name, int line_number) Line 771   C++
ucrtbased.dll!_register_onexit_function::__l23::<lambda>() Line 112 C++
ucrtbased.dll!__crt_seh_guarded_call<int>::operator()<void <lambda>(void),int <lambda>(void) &,void <lambda>(void) >(__acrt_lock_and_call::__l3::void <lambda>(void) && setup, _register_onexit_function::__l23::int <lambda>(void) & action, __acrt_lock_and_call::__l4::void <lambda>(void) && cleanup) Line 199  C++
ucrtbased.dll!__acrt_lock_and_call<int <lambda>(void) >(const __acrt_lock_id lock_id, _register_onexit_function::__l23::int <lambda>(void) && action) Line 882  C++
ucrtbased.dll!_register_onexit_function(_onexit_table_t * table, int (void) * function) Line 148    C++
zwrappers.dll!_onexit(int (void) * function) Line 268   C++
zwrappers.dll!atexit(void (void) * function) Line 276   C++
zwrappers.dll!__scrt_initialize_thread_safe_statics() Line 107  C++
[External Code] 
clrjit.dll!Compiler::impResolveToken(unsigned char const *,struct CORINFO_RESOLVED_TOKEN *,enum CorInfoTokenKind)   Unknown
clrjit.dll!Compiler::impImportBlockCode(struct BasicBlock *)    Unknown
clrjit.dll!Compiler::impImportBlock(struct BasicBlock *)    Unknown
clrjit.dll!Compiler::impImport(struct BasicBlock *) Unknown
clrjit.dll!Compiler::compCompile(void * *,unsigned long *,unsigned int) Unknown
clrjit.dll!Compiler::compCompileHelper(struct CORINFO_MODULE_STRUCT_ *,class ICorJitInfo *,struct CORINFO_METHOD_INFO *,void * *,unsigned long *,unsigned int,enum CorInfoInstantiationVerification)    Unknown
clrjit.dll!Compiler::compCompile(struct CORINFO_METHOD_STRUCT_ *,struct CORINFO_MODULE_STRUCT_ *,class ICorJitInfo *,struct CORINFO_METHOD_INFO *,void * *,unsigned long *,unsigned int)    Unknown
clrjit.dll!jitNativeCode(struct CORINFO_METHOD_STRUCT_ *,struct CORINFO_MODULE_STRUCT_ *,class ICorJitInfo *,struct CORINFO_METHOD_INFO *,void * *,unsigned long *,unsigned int,void *) Unknown
clrjit.dll!CILJit::compileMethod(class ICorJitInfo *,struct CORINFO_METHOD_INFO *,unsigned int,unsigned char * *,unsigned long *)   Unknown
[External Code] 
clrjit.dll!Compiler::impResolveToken(unsigned char const *,struct CORINFO_RESOLVED_TOKEN *,enum CorInfoTokenKind)   Unknown
clrjit.dll!Compiler::impImportBlockCode(struct BasicBlock *)    Unknown
clrjit.dll!Compiler::impImportBlock(struct BasicBlock *)    Unknown
clrjit.dll!Compiler::impImport(struct BasicBlock *) Unknown
clrjit.dll!Compiler::compCompile(void * *,unsigned long *,unsigned int) Unknown
clrjit.dll!Compiler::compCompileHelper(struct CORINFO_MODULE_STRUCT_ *,class ICorJitInfo *,struct CORINFO_METHOD_INFO *,void * *,unsigned long *,unsigned int,enum CorInfoInstantiationVerification)    Unknown
clrjit.dll!Compiler::compCompile(struct CORINFO_METHOD_STRUCT_ *,struct CORINFO_MODULE_STRUCT_ *,class ICorJitInfo *,struct CORINFO_METHOD_INFO *,void * *,unsigned long *,unsigned int)    Unknown
clrjit.dll!jitNativeCode(struct CORINFO_METHOD_STRUCT_ *,struct CORINFO_MODULE_STRUCT_ *,class ICorJitInfo *,struct CORINFO_METHOD_INFO *,void * *,unsigned long *,unsigned int,void *) Unknown
clrjit.dll!CILJit::compileMethod(class ICorJitInfo *,struct CORINFO_METHOD_INFO *,unsigned int,unsigned char * *,unsigned long *)   Unknown
[External Code] 
user32.dll!__InternalCallWinProc@20()   Unknown
user32.dll!UserCallWinProcCheckWow()    Unknown
user32.dll!DispatchMessageWorker()  Unknown
user32.dll!_DispatchMessageW@4()    Unknown
WindowsBase.ni.dll!53fee59c()   Unknown
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, native debugger attempting to walk managed call stack]   
[External Code]
```

The release callstack looks about identical:

```
ntdll.dll!_RtlReportCriticalFailure@8() Unknown
ntdll.dll!_RtlpHeapHandleError@4()  Unknown
ntdll.dll!_RtlpLogHeapFailure@24()  Unknown
ntdll.dll!RtlSizeHeap() Unknown
ucrtbase.dll!_register_onexit_function()    Unknown
zwrappers.dll!_onexit(int (void) * function) Line 268   C++
zwrappers.dll!atexit(void (void) * function) Line 276   C++
zwrappers.dll!__scrt_initialize_thread_safe_statics() Line 107  C++
[External Code] 
clrjit.dll!Compiler::impResolveToken(unsigned char const *,struct CORINFO_RESOLVED_TOKEN *,enum CorInfoTokenKind)   Unknown
clrjit.dll!Compiler::impImportBlockCode(struct BasicBlock *)    Unknown
clrjit.dll!Compiler::impImportBlock(struct BasicBlock *)    Unknown
clrjit.dll!Compiler::impImport(struct BasicBlock *) Unknown
clrjit.dll!Compiler::compCompile(void * *,unsigned long *,unsigned int) Unknown
clrjit.dll!Compiler::compCompileHelper(struct CORINFO_MODULE_STRUCT_ *,class ICorJitInfo *,struct CORINFO_METHOD_INFO *,void * *,unsigned long *,unsigned int,enum CorInfoInstantiationVerification)    Unknown
clrjit.dll!Compiler::compCompile(struct CORINFO_METHOD_STRUCT_ *,struct CORINFO_MODULE_STRUCT_ *,class ICorJitInfo *,struct CORINFO_METHOD_INFO *,void * *,unsigned long *,unsigned int)    Unknown
clrjit.dll!jitNativeCode(struct CORINFO_METHOD_STRUCT_ *,struct CORINFO_MODULE_STRUCT_ *,class ICorJitInfo *,struct CORINFO_METHOD_INFO *,void * *,unsigned long *,unsigned int,void *) Unknown
clrjit.dll!CILJit::compileMethod(class ICorJitInfo *,struct CORINFO_METHOD_INFO *,unsigned int,unsigned char * *,unsigned long *)   Unknown
[External Code] 
clrjit.dll!Compiler::impResolveToken(unsigned char const *,struct CORINFO_RESOLVED_TOKEN *,enum CorInfoTokenKind)   Unknown
clrjit.dll!Compiler::impImportBlockCode(struct BasicBlock *)    Unknown
clrjit.dll!Compiler::impImportBlock(struct BasicBlock *)    Unknown
clrjit.dll!Compiler::impImport(struct BasicBlock *) Unknown
clrjit.dll!Compiler::compCompile(void * *,unsigned long *,unsigned int) Unknown
clrjit.dll!Compiler::compCompileHelper(struct CORINFO_MODULE_STRUCT_ *,class ICorJitInfo *,struct CORINFO_METHOD_INFO *,void * *,unsigned long *,unsigned int,enum CorInfoInstantiationVerification)    Unknown
clrjit.dll!Compiler::compCompile(struct CORINFO_METHOD_STRUCT_ *,struct CORINFO_MODULE_STRUCT_ *,class ICorJitInfo *,struct CORINFO_METHOD_INFO *,void * *,unsigned long *,unsigned int)    Unknown
clrjit.dll!jitNativeCode(struct CORINFO_METHOD_STRUCT_ *,struct CORINFO_MODULE_STRUCT_ *,class ICorJitInfo *,struct CORINFO_METHOD_INFO *,void * *,unsigned long *,unsigned int,void *) Unknown
clrjit.dll!CILJit::compileMethod(class ICorJitInfo *,struct CORINFO_METHOD_INFO *,unsigned int,unsigned char * *,unsigned long *)   Unknown
[External Code] 
user32.dll!__InternalCallWinProc@20()   Unknown
user32.dll!UserCallWinProcCheckWow()    Unknown
user32.dll!DispatchMessageWorker()  Unknown
user32.dll!_DispatchMessageW@4()    Unknown
WindowsBase.ni.dll!53fee59c()   Unknown
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, native debugger attempting to walk managed call stack]   
[External Code]
```

Comment: Are all the dependent modules (loaded into the process) also built with VC++ 2015?

Comment: Is all of the C++ code changed to use VS 2015 C++ compiler, or is everyting still using VS 2010 C++ compiler?

Comment: I have recompiled everything that I have source for with 2015.

Comment: Have you tried disabling RyuJIT, just might help.

Comment: Hmm, guess that's another useful bit. This is compiled 32 bit, and the .NET clients are set to x86, not any cpu. Worth a shot though. Tried adding     <runtime>
      <useLegacyJit enabled="1" />
    </runtime> but it had no impact.

Comment: Can you set the debugger call stack during the crash to the impResolveToken frame and dump what the name of the token it's trying to resolve from zwrappers.dll is? It appears to me that perhaps you have some global statics in zwrappers.dll who are interdependent and the construction order is different with the 2015-generated code.

Comment: That seems like a logical conclusion, @jschroedl. Unfortunately, I'm not getting any info in Autos/Locals when I switch to that frame, nor do breakpoints in the callstack stop. Is there some way I can break in here to get this info?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the exact same problem. At least in my case, the problem was the /NOENTRY switch in "Additional Options" in the linker switches. This is *only* visible when "All Options" is selected in the linker settings. Removing /NOENTRY also removed the problem.

My original (2013) project file did have this switch; however, the 2013 build did work. So either that switch was ignored in 2013, or the whole linking process has changed. (which from the looks i assume it has quite a bit.)

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try on Monday!

Comment: This does seem to get the product past the crash we were having earlier. I'm having other issues, but I think they're unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you are mixing up debug and release code? *ucrtbased.dll* is the debug universal CRT DLL. Windows maintains different heaps for debug versus release and mixing them can definitely cause errors like these. The different C runtime DLL's (e.g., VS2010, 2012, 2015) also maintain different heaps. Allocating memory on one heap and deallocating on another will cause these types of errors too.

See http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/29475-HEAP-VariousTests-exe-Invalid-Address-specified-to-RtlValidateHeap for example.

Comment: The issue happens in Debug and Release mode and I have pretty well defined debug/release separation, so I doubt that's the issue. Also, no naming etc. changes were made with the port and this issue did not exist before.