# Access violation in Windows Form project that uses fstream in a library

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2015, c++-cli, fstream

I have a lib project with a few utility functions of mine and it works fine with console applications.

Now I started a Windows Form application, included that lib and it gives me an "Exception thrown at 0xxxx (ntdll.dll) in : 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xxxx."

The application code is just the code Visual Studio added to the new project. No code of my own added, except the #include of my lib header.

I commented my lib code, piece by piece and found that when I comment the line "ofstream MyLog;" the exception goes away.

I did rebuild this project from scratch a couple of time: same results. Pretty much: (1) Create new WinForm project, (2) add existing project MyLibTest, (3) 'Add reference...' to connect them, (4) add the #include in the main cpp and (5) run it.

I dont know if this is relevant, but since I started this WinForm project, Visual Studio spent many, many hours downloading symbols from Microsoft Symbol Server. (elsewhere here at stackoverflow it is said that this MS server is really slow)

This is relevant: I am new to c++ and I have created several mini projects in Visual Studio 2015 to experiment with several aspects of the language (file reading, classes, string manipulation, vectors, lists, Windows forms, etc). Now I am trying to put all of them together.

My code

```
//------ MyLibTest.h --------

#pragma once

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <time.h>
#include <cstdarg>
#include <memory>


//------ MyLibTest.cpp --------

#include "MyLibTEST.h"

using namespace std;

ofstream MyLog;     // <<<< if i comment this line, the Access violation exception does not happen
```

WinForm application CODE added by Visual Studio 2015

```
//------ MyForm.h --------

 #pragma once

namespace MyWindowsFormTest {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for MyForm
    /// </summary>
    public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        MyForm(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~MyForm()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->components = gcnew System::ComponentModel::Container();
            this->Size = System::Drawing::Size(300,300);
            this->Text = L"MyForm";
            this->Padding = System::Windows::Forms::Padding(0);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
        }
#pragma endregion
    };
}

//------ MyForm.cpp --------

#include "Q:\MyDesv\Visual Studio Projects\Projects\MyLibTest\MyLib\MyLibTest.h"

#include "MyForm.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;


[STAThread]
void Main(array<String^>^ args)
{
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    MyWindowsFormTest::MyForm form;
    Application::Run(%form);
}
```

Call Stack

```
    ntdll.dll!RtlValidateHeap() Unknown
    KernelBase.dll!_HeapValidate@12()   Unknown
>   ucrtbased.dll!_CrtIsValidHeapPointer(const void * block) Line 1407  C++
    ucrtbased.dll!_msize_dbg(void * block, int block_use) Line 1059 C++
    ucrtbased.dll!_msize(void * block) Line 38  C++
    ucrtbased.dll!_recalloc_dbg(void * block, unsigned int count, unsigned int element_size, int block_use, const char * file_name, int line_number) Line 784   C++
    ucrtbased.dll!_register_onexit_function::__l2::<lambda>() Line 112  C++
    ucrtbased.dll!__crt_seh_guarded_call<int>::operator()<void <lambda>(void),int <lambda>(void) &,void <lambda>(void) >(__acrt_lock_and_call::__l2::void <lambda>(void) && setup, _register_onexit_function::__l2::int <lambda>(void) & action, __acrt_lock_and_call::__l2::void <lambda>(void) && cleanup) Line 204   C++
    ucrtbased.dll!__acrt_lock_and_call<int <lambda>(void) >(const __acrt_lock_id lock_id, _register_onexit_function::__l2::int <lambda>(void) && action) Line 912   C++
    ucrtbased.dll!_register_onexit_function(_onexit_table_t * table, int(*)() function) Line 84 C++
    CppWinForm2.exe!_onexit(int(*)() function) Line 268 C++
    CppWinForm2.exe!atexit(void(*)() function) Line 276 C++
    CppWinForm2.exe!std::`dynamic initializer for '_Fac_tidy_reg''() Line 65    C++
    [External Code] 
    mscoreei.dll!__CorExeMain@0()   Unknown
    mscoree.dll!__CorExeMain_Exported@0()   Unknown
    kernel32.dll!@BaseThreadInitThunk@12()  Unknown
    ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart()    Unknown
    ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart@8()  Unknown
```

Comment: *Windows forms* -- Windows Forms are not part of the C++ language.  The code you posted isn't even C++.

Comment: Well . . . that is the code Visual Studio 2015 generates when i create a new project and choose "C++ Windows Forms"

Comment: You should get more familiar with the tools you're using.  What was generated is not `C++`, but something called `Managed C++` or `C++/CLI` which is a hybrid of some C++ and Microsoft syntax that is nowhere close to C++.  Stuff like this: `void Main(array<String^>^ args)` does not exist in C++.  I wouldn't be the least bit surprised if the problem is that you're mixing languages (C++ with C++/CLI) and C++/CLI doesn't play nice with C++ classes.

Comment: I suppose I should re-flag my question as C++/CLI, then. (but I do not know how). But it does not seem to be be a language incompatibility, because if I move the very same code from the .lib to the main project, it works fine.

Comment: A Winforms program built with VS2015 tends to suffer from a very gritty initialization problem.  You need to post the content of the Call Stack window when you get the exception so we can see if it is match.  There is [one existing Q+A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32914250/c-cli-dll-crashes-on-load-after-port-to-vs2015-net-4-6/35363914#35363914) that talks about it, but I'm fairly sure that it isn't just limited to /NOENTRY.  Cold hard fact is that the project template was removed in VS2012 and pieces keep falling off.

Comment: Call Stack contents added to the post. Initialization problem fits, because, the exception occurs before the the very first line in the main function if I add a breakpoint there, Checked the /NOENTRY and it is not selected. (also changed the tag from C++  to c++/cli.)

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue (since around 2007). It is related to having a winforms project with native C++ static objects. It seems that Winform projects by default skip the crt initialization, which obviously has an impact on any static objects.

You can read more about it in [This link from a Microsoft support person](https://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/642179-c-cli-winforms-app-native-static-library-singletons-cra) and [This link from another stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41485935/entry-point-for-c-cli-x64-windowsforms-app-vs-2015).

Basically your Winforms project has a `Main` function that looks something like

```
[STAThread]
void Main(array<String^>^ args)
{
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    MyWindowsFormTest::MyForm form;
    Application::Run(%form);
}
```

First step is change the main declaration to:

```
int main(..)
```

Then go Project->Properties->Linker->Advanced->Entry Point. Change this from "Main" to something like "?mainCRTStartupStrArray@@$$FYMHP$01EAPE$AAVString@System@@@Z". This may vary depending on your VS version.

IMO though, unless you are deep into project development rather don't use WinForms. As I understand it, the support is discontinued... .