# Entry point for C++/CLI x64 WindowsForms App (VS 2015)

Tags: c++-cli

I have the same problem as the user in [Visual Studio 2015 c++/CLI boost::thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40081419/visual-studio-2015-c-cli-boostthread) : If I use boost, Windows Forms and C++/Cli together, my app crashes on startup.

The proposed solution works for me (change Subsystem to Console); the only small disadvantage is that the console is started alongside the GUI.

There is another solution I've found (see https://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/642179-c-cli-winforms-app-native-static-library-singletons-cra) : Changing the entry point to "?mainCRTStartupStrArray@@$$FYMHP$01AP$AAVString@System@@@Z".

However this only works when compiling for 32 bit; for 64 bit the symbol cannot be resolved.
My questions:

- Is there a similar symbol that works for x64 as well?
- How could one find these kind of symbols? I tried to locate them via dumpbin but with no success!

Comment: I know this isn't a direct answer to your question, but would switching to [.Net Threads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx) work for you? If not, can you explain briefly why boost threads are required?

Comment: @DavidYaw: Could be, but I have to use existing C++ code that uses boost threads internally, so switching is not an option!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, light at the end of the tunnel for this nasty ignored problem.  You can find the correct mangled name by grepping the .lib files in vc/lib/amd64.  Out pops msvcmrt.lib, the name is:

```
?mainCRTStartupStrArray@@$$FYMHP$01EAPE$AAVString@System@@@Z
```

Bit of a bug in the mangling algorithm btw, it shouldn't have added the extra E's because these are managed identifiers.  Links and runs fine, I haven't tested yet if it solves the static initialization order fiasco problem.  It is promising.

Comment: Thanks Hans, I'll test it tomorrow. Could you elaborate what you did exactly when "grepping the .lib files"?

Comment: Just a text search in a binary file.  I use the Far file manager, it makes this easy.